# como ajustar los tamaños de card de bootstrap 5 segun el tamaño de un div padre

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, card

Hola buenas tardes estoy creando una api web pero tengo un problema estético, y es que tengo unos servicios que al traerlos de la base de datos los muestro en card de bootstrap 5, este esta adentro de un div padre, pero hay unos services que tienes solo dos productos y otros que tienen 3 me gustaría, que se ajustara las card, o por lo menos que se centren y no quede un vacío.
asi es como se ven aquellos servicios que tiene 3 productos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como se ve cuando hay solo dos y no me agrada como se ve el espacio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podria solucionar este problema estetico, que cuando sean 2 se acomode al div padre o por lo menos que se centren y queden con un margen igual izq y derecha, este es mi codigo

```
<Fragment>
  {loading ? <div className='d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-5'>
    <h2 className='quantify text-white'> Loading...</h2>
  </div> : (
    <Fragment>
      <Metadata title={service.nombre}></Metadata>
      <div className='container container-fluid'>
        <div className='d-flex  justify-content-center align-items-center'>
          <div className='border border-danger w-50 mt-5 mb-5'>
            <h1 className='text-danger text-center quantify'><b>Services Details</b></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='d-flex  justify-content-center align-items-center h-50'>
          <div className='border border-danger w-75 mt-1 mb-5  p-2'>
            <div className='container'>
              <div className='scroll row'>
                {service.producto && service.producto.map(product => (
                  <div key={product.public_id} className="col-12 col-md-6" id='detalles_services'>
                    <div className="card rounded bg-danger m-1 h-100 ">
                      <h2 className='text-white modern card-header'>Servicio # {product.public_id} </h2>
                      <div className="card-body cardBody d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center h-75 w-auto">
                        <p className='text-secondary cafe' > {product.descripcion_producto} </p>
                        <h5 className='text-white'> <hr></hr>${product.precio} <hr></hr> </h5>
                        <Link to={`/preinscription`} id="button" type='button' className="btn btn-outline-danger w-50 ms-10 text-white cafe"> Book Now <i class="bi bi-clipboard-check"></i></Link>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )}
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Poco te podríamos ayudar si no agregas tu código en formato código. Pero deduciendo el problema es que le falta un `justify-content: center` a tu div contenedor padre de las tarjetas

Comment: si tengo <div className='container container-fluid'>
            <div className='d-flex  justify-content-center align-items-center'>
              <div className='border border-danger w-50 mt-5 mb-5'>
                <h1 className='text-danger text-center quantify'><b>Services Details</b></h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='d-flex  justify-content-center align-items-center h-50'>

Comment: ¿Las tarjetas están en el div `scroll row`? Entonces ese es su contenedor la cuan debe ser `justify-content-center`

Comment: muchas gracias si era eso. pero de repente me quedaron las tarjetas de diferentes tamaños de alto. sabes de casualidad como podria hacer que todas me queden del mismo tamaño

Comment: Hay muchas cosas que ver, pero no agregaste todos tus códigos (CSS y HTML) para resolver. ¿El scroll de este contenedor es horizontal ó vertical? Si es scroll horizontal, se podría darle un `height` fijo; ó a las tarjetas. Pero es díficil porque al hacer una cosa, surge otra cosa. Por eso puedes editar tu pregunta y agrega tu código CSS y HTML con el icono **{ }**